# Passing generic into a class constructor list

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class that takes a generic as a parameter like this

```
public MyNewClass(string text, T myClass, int f, bool test = false)
```

The compiler is complaining about `T myClass`.

I know I can pass "defined" generic classes to a class constructor (such as `List`, `Dictionary` etc) and have seen that this can be done in C# as well, but can't find a reference to it.

Comment: What do you mean by *can't find a reference to it*? Do you mean how to define a generic class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare the generic parameter, when you declare your class.

```
public class MyNewClass<T>
{


}
```

Then this parameter could be accessible from any of the class's methods. When you will create an instance of your `MyNewClass`, you should define also the type of T, for instance:

```
var instanceOfMyNewClass = new MyNewClass<className>(text, classIntance, f, true);
```

where `classInstance` is an instance of an object of type `className`.

A good introduction about generics is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I've used generics for quite a while now, just not in this way, but a refresher is always good :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue you are facing is that the following does not compile

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo(string s, T t) { }
}

var foo = new Foo("Hello", new Something());
```

The fix to this is to specify  in the constructor.

```
var foo = new Foo<Something>("Hello", new Something());
```

However, this still seems a little strange given that normally, the C# compiler can infer the type of `T`.

The problem here is that the C# compiler is only allowed to infer generics on the first parameter of a method. So the following IS allowed.

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo(T t, string s) { }
}

var foo = new Foo(new Something(), "Hello");
```